# Trying to understand Django's sorl-thumbnail

Tags: python, django, image-processing

I have been playing around with `sorl-thumbnail` for Django. And trying to understand how it works better.

I've read the guide for it, installed it in my site-packages, made sure PIL is installed correctly, put `sorl.thumbnail` in the `INSTALLED APPS` in my **settings.py**, put `from sorl.thumbnail.fields import ImageWithThumbnailsField` at the top in my **models.py**, added `image = ImageWithThumbnailsField(upload to="images/", thumbnail={'size':(80, 80)})` as one of my model fields, passed the model through my view to the template, and in the template added `{% load thumbnail %}` at the top and put in the variable `{{ mymodel.image.thumbnail_tag }}` in there too.

But from what I understood is that when I upload an image through the admin, it would create the thumbnail straight away, but it only actually creates in when I see my template in the browser? Is this correct? The thumbnail shows fine, it looks great in fact, but I thought that adding the model field part of it would create the thumbnail instantly once the image has uploaded? ...Why not just use the `models.ImageField` in my model instead?

...or have I done this all OK and I've just got the way it works wrong?

Comment: Thumbnail is created once, when called to be displayed for the first time. AFAIK the main and probably only reason to use ImageWithThumbnailsField is that it lets you display thumbs in the admin list with no special effort.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the sorl-thumbnail developers.

Firstly, you don't need to `{% load thumbnail %}` unless you're just using the thumbnail tag rather than a thumbnail field.

Currently, a thumbnail is only ever created the first time it is used - even if you use the field [I'll get around to changing that one day if no-one else does first]. The advantage of the field is that you can specify the sizing rather than giving the freedom to the designer in the template level [and making it easier for an admin thumbnail].

Both ways work, you get to decide which works best for you.

Comment: Thank you Chris for making it clear. Is there any documentation on getting the admin thumbnail working? I'm not sure how to implement that side of sorl-thumnbail...

Comment: Note: I just added the functionality to generate images on save. As always, you can check out the readme for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding some jCrop in the admin to specify area of thumbnail ? Woul be pretty cool :)